# Hotjar survey via javascript trigger with Google Tag manager not loading on first history change

Tags: reactjs, google-tag-manager, hotjar, sharetribe

I have a sharetribe react application which has google tag manager implemented.

Have added the Google Tag Manager tag below to be triggered on all history changes.
hj('trigger', 'listing_upload_canceled')
[image: Tag Config Image]

When When I test it out on Tag Manager Preview, I and change the page on my single page application I can see that the tag is fired successfully, but the hj survey doesn't load.

When I click on the same navigation option and a second history event occurs the survey will load. When I load refresh the page entirely as well the survey will load. It seems to be ignoring the first pushstate history change when I visit any path of my react app but will load the survey on the second pushstate history change.

Comment: Hi there! It may bu just that your local storage item is not there on the first history change, which would be the case if you populate it on history change too. I suggest checking where you're setting your triggerSurvey. If you see that the tag fired, that means the JS has executed. Oh, also it's possible that the hj object is undefined, especially if you're loading it on history change rather than pageload. Check the JS errors too then.

Comment: @Cthulchu Thanks so much for the suggestion, I had already checked that the local storage item is coming up on the first history change. I added another quick check to see if hj object was undefined but I got the expected response in the console: 

VM293:1 ƒ (){(a.hj.q=a.hj.q||[]).push(arguments)}

Comment: what about the hj() function? Maybe it's not defined at that point? Do you see JS errors on the first history change? Also, have you tried executing the hj() function manually after the first history change when it seemingly is not executed?

It's just that if the html tag fired, you will be able to see the <script> added to the DOM. Therefore, evaluated.

Comment: I have a VERY similar issue when I was just trying to log page_view events based on history changes. I think there is actually a bug in the 'Preview' feature of GTM that doesn't properly trigger history change events for the INITIAL navigation. When I actually deployed it then it was giving a history event for the initial navigation. This is an Angular app but sounds very similar. Try deploying and not using the 'Preview' feature. I tried a dozen times with even the simplest pages on my site and got no initial event when 'Preview' was open.